# Swift: safe area on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, iphone-x

I have `ViewController` with `collectionView` and `collectionView` bottom, top, leading, trailing constraints to superview. And on iPhone 8 my screen look like this:

[image]

And for another devices all looks fine. But on iPhone X look like this:

[image]

I use this code for my cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let offset: CGFloat = 10
    let width = collectionView.bounds.width / 3  - offset * 4
    let a: CGFloat = width / 2
    let b: CGFloat = a * 3 + a * 0.65
    let height = b

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height) 

    }
```

How to fix it?

**Update**

constraints:

[image]

Comment: What is that black screen?

Comment: remove the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints of your collectionview and add top, bottom , leading and trailing constraints from safe area it will work surely.

Comment: @dahiya_boy 3 black rectangles are the collectionView cells

Comment: @Y_Y I need to use  leading and trailing constraints of my `collection-view` that if I scroll left or right my content should showing from left or right edge of screen. Or if I use safe area my content showing from safe area.

Comment: @111 Can you actually define what is your required o/p??

Comment: @dahiya_boy I need that my content to be displayed correctly. And I need to have leading and trailing constraints of my `collection-view`

Comment: @dahiya_boy Also if I use top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints of collectionview to safe area my content look like in 2 image.

Comment: @Y_Y Also if I use top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints of collectionview to safe area my content look like in 2 image.

Comment: safe area will be visible in the case of iphone x otherwise it is same as the superview. so in your case by adding trailing and leading constraints it would not create any problem as safe area will affect the top and bottom of your collectionview.

Comment: @Y_Y https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljysx.png The content is covered by the top edge of the screen

Comment: @111 Show me your contraints??

Comment: @dahiya_boy I updated question.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Have you looked at my contraints? What should I do?

Comment: @111 Check my answer. I used your details and prepare my demo. It is working. For more details, better if you give me your sample project.

Comment: IMO, the issue is in the item size calculation. iPhone 8 resolution is 1334x750. In landscape the height of the cell will be 738 which is less than 750 (it fits). On the other hand iPhone X resolution is 2436x1125. If I'm not wrong item height will be 1408,9 which is bigger than 1125.

Comment: @apetrov On other devices(iPad, iPhone) everything displayed correctly. Just about like on iPhone 8 with space from all edges.

Comment: @apetrov I want to on iPhone X my cells similar looks like on iPhone 8. But if I change `collectionView.bounds.width` on `667` in my code  I can see fourth cell on my iPhone X screen. But I need have only 3 cells on screen.

Comment: @apetrov Could you give the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your details I got below output.

[image]

> NOTE: In landscape mode safearea of top is zero.

**Constraints :**

[image]

**SizeForItem :**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let offset: CGFloat = 10
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width / 3  - offset * 4
        let a: CGFloat = width / 2
        let b: CGFloat = a * 3 + a * 0.65
        let height = b

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

> Edit : Check is this o/p is not for you or not. So that I will explain. And if you wanted to cover the safe area then it is not possible.

**Iphone X**

[image]

**Iphone 8**

[image]

Comment: I have same result. But I need to have space on the top constraint like on iPhone 8. And my contentView should have leading and trailing constraints to superview.

Comment: @111 for that you have to give constant space from `safe.area` .

Comment: I think that @apetrov it right. Please check comments under question. What you think about it?

Comment: @111 Cell size is calculated with the size of collectionView size. As you have given the top space as zero so it sticks to the top. Give constant space and check.

Comment: On each devices this space is different. If I give constant space my proportions of cell will be broken.

Comment: I found a solution but I can not figure out how to do it. I need to change `collectionView.bounds.width` on `667` in my code. But in this case I can see fourth cell on my iPhone X screen. But I need have only 3 cells on screen. How to fix it?

Comment: You have different aspect ratio for iPhone 8 and iPhone X. I need something like this: https://ibb.co/cH24gd (same aspect ratio minus bottom safe are)